# Expansion of interaction potential in terms of spherical harmonics in unconventional superconductivity

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, spherical-harmonics, special-functions

I am currently reading the book *Introduction to Unconventional Superconductivity* by V. P. Mineev and K. V. Samokhin. In Equation (1.6), the interaction potential $V$ is expanded in terms of spherical harmonics as follows:

$$V\left(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}^{\prime}\right)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}V_{l}\left(k,k^{\prime}\right)\sum_{m=-l}^{l}Y_{lm}\left(\hat{\mathbf{k}}\right)Y^{*}_{lm}\left(\hat{\mathbf{k}}^{\prime}\right).$$

This appears to be a general expression, assuming the potential is a function of the difference of momenta $\mathbf{q}=\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}^{\prime}$. However, I am struggling to understand how this equation is derived.

From my understanding, the potential could be expanded as

$$V\left(\mathbf{k},\mathbf{k}^{\prime}\right)=\sum_{lm,l^{\prime}m^{\prime}}V_{lm,l^{\prime}m^{\prime}}\left(k,k^{\prime}\right)Y_{lm}\left(\hat{\mathbf{k}}\right)Y_{l^{\prime}m^{\prime}}\left(\hat{\mathbf{k}}^{\prime}\right),$$

where

$$V_{lm,l^{\prime}m^{\prime}}=\int d\Omega\int d\Omega^{\prime}Y_{lm}^{*}\left(\hat{\mathbf{k}}\right)Y_{l^{\prime}m^{\prime}}^{*}\left(\hat{\mathbf{k}}^{\prime}\right)V\left(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}^{\prime}\right).$$

In order to arrive at the equation given in the book, it seems necessary that

$$V_{lm,l^{\prime}m^{\prime}} = \delta_{ll^{\prime}}\delta_{mm^{\prime}}V_{l}(k,k^{\prime}).$$

However, I am unsure how to proceed from here. I would appreciate any guidance or insights into this derivation.

Comment: You have some minor mistakes, and that prevents you from being able to get a proof. However, the proof of this is quite involved, and it is much more common to note that this is a general result rather than do it for your specific case. It belongs in a mathematical methods textbook rather than in any specific application subfield, and is just imported for use in each subfield. You should look that up there.

Comment: The potential here is rotationally invariant, so it is a function of just k,k' and ${\bf \hat k \cdot \hat k'}$. The $m$ sum over the spherical harmonics is proportional to $P_l({\bf \hat k \cdot \hat k'})$ from the spherical harmonic addition theorem.

Comment: @user200143 thank you, that works!